# Was Q Created in the very first Star Trek Movie?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-q

This question is based off the end of the very first Star Trek Movie, so I will ask it in spoilers in the odd case that you haven't seen it yet.

> At the end of the movie Kirk asked Bones and Spock if they had just witnessed the making/creation of a new species.  during the Movie they gathered that the Voyager Satellite/probe had possibly gone through a worm hole that took it to the other side of the universe and possibly through time.  So my thoughts are that the merged species disappeared possibly through time.

could this theoretically have been the beginning of the Q?

Comment: Related to [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3168/where-did-the-q-come-from-before-the-q-continuum)

Comment: @EngineerToast - More than just related.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the probe featured in *Star Trek: The Motion Picture*—known as V’Ger/Vejur—was not related to the Q Continuum in any fashion. Also, there was no mention of the probe travelling through time, only space. To be precise, it was said that the probe had travelled through a black hole and found itself on the “far side of the galaxy” where it crashed on a “machine planet” inhabited by sentient machines.

The machines believed the Voyager probe to be like them—much as a child—and built the vessel around it so that it might fulfill it’s primary programming: To learn all there is to learn and then return to its creator.

> **KIRK:** V-G-E-R ...V-O-Y-A-G-E-R ...Voyager! ...Voyager VI?
>
> **DECKER:** NASA. National Aeronautics and Space Administration. Jim, this was launched more than three hundred years ago.
>
> **KIRK:** Voyager series, designed to collect data and transmit it back to Earth.
>
> **DECKER:** Voyager VI …disappeared into what they used to call a black hole.
>
> **KIRK:** It must have emerged sometime on the far side of the Galaxy and fell into the machine’s planet’s gravitational field.
>
> **SPOCK:** The machine inhabitants found it to be one of their own kind, primitive yet kindred. They discovered its simple
>   twentieth-century programming. Collect all data possible.
>
> **DECKER:** Learn all that is learnable. Return that information to its Creator.
>
> **SPOCK (OC):** Precisely, Mister Decker, the machines interpreted it literally. They built this entire vessel so that Voyager could fulfill
>   it’s programming.
>
> **KIRK:** And on its journey back it amassed so much knowledge, it achieved consciousness itself. It became a living thing.

To date, no further information about the “machine planet” or its inhabitants has been revealed. However, [Gene Roddenberry himself speculated](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/884/was-vger-responsible-for-the-creation-of-the-borg) that:

> The “machine race” that built the probe around V'Ger was actually the Borg. However, he may have been joking at the time.

Comment: whatever came out of the merging at the end went into a different dimension, could it be possible that they traveled through time and observed everything from the beginning of time? and thus every mention of the Q as always existing would be true? they have been known to travel through time, and there wasn't much given about the capabilities of the being that disappeared at the end into another dimension.

Comment: Have you got a link to that Roddenberry quote? You might want to [add it here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/426/what-was-the-origin-of-star-treks-borg).

Comment: @Malachi - I see what you're getting at, but if we're going to guess I think it's more likely that the merged V'Ger would be the origin of the modern Borg (a human/machine hybrid) instead of the Q.

Comment: @Wikis - unfortunately not. It was one of the last interviews he gave before his death, apparently shortly after the TNG episode "Q Who?" aired. The topic of the interview was this new enemy called The Borg and how they came to be. Roddenberry brought up the machine planet from ST:TMP as a possible origin. Many people have said he was probably joking, though. Since he died before setting the record straight, it's impossible to know now.

Comment: Time Travel will have to settle that argument @Omegacron...lol

Comment: He only gave a handful of interviews in the time between the episode airing in 1989 and his death in 1991. The most likely culprits are one of the two in Star Trek magazine. I have something like 30 issues at home but I'll have to dig 'em out & see if I can find the interview in question.

Comment: FYI - turns out I have a lot more than 30 issues. I got through a dozen or so and gave up. Hopefully someone with more patience than me can find the interview.